# Using microsoft calendar I'm trying to get access token using authorization code but every time get error message like “invalid_grant”

Tags: oauth-2.0, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365, single-sign-on

```
I tried get access token from microsoft example from here https://insen.github.io/blog/2017/09/24/Azure-AAD-with-Office-365/ No matter which property I use, I always get the 400 "invalid_grant" error. Anyone can help?
    
POST: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/[tenantId]/oauth2/token"
    
Content Type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
    
Data: 
client_id: [clientId]
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/calendars.read
code: M.R3_BAY.6c27a84e-f211-c632-9298-c97ba411256b
redirect_uri: http://localhost/myapp/
grant_type: authorization_code
client_secret: [clientSecret]
```

Response:
{
"error": "invalid_grant",
"error_description": "AADSTS9002313: Invalid request. Request is malformed or
invalid.",
"error_codes": [
9002313
],
"timestamp": "2021-08-10 12:35:00Z",
"trace_id": "50ba80c2-7920-48bd-aee0-cab1b5baf801",
"correlation_id": "44fcb62f-b5f0-41f4-b596-b4abf74c2c55",
"error_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=9002313"
}

Comment: (1) Validate the token and see whether the above user has necessary permissions/scopes and roles assigned (2) You can test the above [auth code flow example using POSTMAN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) in the example as well, so that you can isolate the issue outside of your app as well